# composer error when try to update

Tags: composer-php, laravel-5

I tried to update my project dependencies using composer update, but I got error:

Where to dig for such an error?

```
C:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.6.18-0\apps\project>composer update
> php artisan clear-compiled
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.15
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.2.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.1
    - laravelcollective/html v5.1.0 requires illuminate/session 5.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/session[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.1.1 requires illuminate/session 5.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/session[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.1.2 requires illuminate/session 5.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/session[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.1.3 requires illuminate/session 5.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/session[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.1.4 requires illuminate/session 5.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/session[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.1.5 requires illuminate/session 5.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/session[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.1.6 requires illuminate/session 5.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/session[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.1.7 requires illuminate/session 5.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/session[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.1.8 requires illuminate/session 5.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/session[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.1.9 requires illuminate/session 5.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/session[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.1.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.1.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.1.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.1.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.1.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.1.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.1.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.2.0, v5.2.1, v5.2.10, v5.2.11, v5.2.12, v5.2.13, v5.2.14, v5.2.15, v5.2.16, v5.2.2, v5.2.3, v5.2.4, v5.2.5, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.2.8, v5.2.9].
    - Installation request for laravelcollective/html 5.1.* -> satisfiable by laravelcollective/html[v5.1.0, v5.1.1, v5.1.2, v5.1.3, v5.1.4, v5.1.5, v5.1.6, v5.1.7, v5.1.8, v5.1.9].
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by requesting a more updated version of laravelcollective: `"laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*-dev"`

Comment: Using a dev branch is always dangerous because it usually contains code that is not thoroughly tested